# WCF: Randomly does not respond

Tags: wcf, silverlight, response, basichttpbinding, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have a peculiar problem with client requests randomly not getting a response to a WCF service call.

The setup is a Silverlight 5 application making calls to a WCF service, using both HTTP and PollingDuplex bindings. The SL makes a number of requests upon loading (20+ in 20s), and every now and then does not receive a response to one or two of them. To be clear, the exact same request works 90% of time, if I refresh the page all requests could get a response.

The error cannot be the actual request sent. I use Fiddler to validate this as well, since I see the request being made (make sure the content is the same as previous successful requests), but there is no response to the request. Eventually the client times out the request. The WCF service is hosted in IIS7, and I have diagnostics and logging enabled on both. In the WCF server trace logs, I only see message logged when the client times the request out. It has the following exception action logged under a "Processing message" activity, at the time of the client timing out:
"The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header.  There may have been a network error or the client may be sending invalid requests."
This is as if the body of the HTTP is not getting through to WCF (I do not know if I can log the full request received by IIS before passing to WCF handlers?). As I said, using Fiddler I can see the full message is valid (note that this behaviour also occurs when Fiddler is not sniffing the traffic, so I've ruled Fiddler out as the problem).

Typically the "Processing message" activity has a "To: Process action *xxx*"

Like I said this occurs with Http and PollingDuplex services, on my dev box as well as production web servers. Occurs on different endpoints as well, and I don't think it has to do with WCF throttling behaviour, since it occurs

Any information or help will be appreciated to get to the cause, whether it's additional information I can gather to help diagnose or any hints.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.